# Issues with setting layout of objects in widget on iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: iphone, swift, notificationcenter

I have added a widget to my app but I am having issues with running it on the iPhone 6 Plus.

Basically, the issue is that the iPhone 6 Plus has borders around the notification centre, whereas every other screen size does not. The way I have programmed my widget means that labels are getting cut off on the iPhone 6 Plus as I am not using Auto-Layout.

I have tried adding some code that changes the position of the labels if the widget detects it is being run on an iPhone 6 Plus. For some reason the code doesn't seem to be working however.

Here is my code:

```
        totalBudgetDisplay.frame.origin.x = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 186
    currentBudgetDisplay.frame.origin.x = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 186
    budgetNameDisplay.frame.origin.x = 16
    warningLabel.center = view.center
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.bounds.width, view.bounds.height)

    var height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape && height == 540 {
        totalBudgetDisplay.frame.origin.x = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 250
        currentBudgetDisplay.frame.origin.x = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 250
        budgetNameDisplay.frame.origin.x = 80
        warningLabel.center = view.center
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.bounds.width, view.bounds.height)
    }
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I should mention that the issue is that the labels do not move when run on iPhone 6 Plus. They just stay in the positions that they should be for other screens. I'm not sure if I am checking for the wrong height or something? Also, it's only an issue in landscape orientation.